# Override dynamic files in Chrome Overrides

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've tried to use Google Chrome Overrides to modify a JavaScript file before it is loaded. The file has a path like this: `https://website.org/assets/_pc1GX2/compiled/StaticName.js`
But this part in the middle:
`https://website.org/assets/[DynamicIndex]/compiled/StaticName.js`
changes once every week or two. 
So I have to go to the overrides tab and do everything again.
Because Chrome Overrides only work with urls/paths, and not with file names directly. 
Is there a way to use local overrides on the file named `[StaticName.js]` without taking the changing path (file's url) into account? Because the file's name always stays the same, only the url changes.
Or is there some way to do this with a Chrome extension?

Comment: There are extensions that allow you to specify URL redirection rules, should be easy to find. As for implementing one yourself, you would need to use [chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest).

Comment: Thanks, webRequest seems to work great, and it's also possible to specify any rules for which urls to redirect